# The kernel of a group action defined by left multiplication on left cosets of $H\leq G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a subgroup $H\leq G$, for $G$ finite.  Let $G$ act on the left cosets of $H$ by left multiplication.  What is the kernel of this group action?

Since the left cosets are themselves constructed by left multiplication, wouldn't the kernel of this map just be equal to $H$?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the action of $g$ on $g'H$. Then:
$g$ acts trivially on $g'H$ for every $g' \in G$ $\leftrightarrow $  $gg'H=g'H$ for every $g'$. Taking $g'=$identity element, you see $g \in H$. But unless $H$ is normal, $h \in H$: $hg'H \ne g'H$ does not hold for all $h \in H$ and $g'\in G$. For example take 
$H=\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix},n \in \Bbb N\}$, $h=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$,$g'=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4  \end{pmatrix}$. Then $g'^{-1}hg'Id_n=\begin{pmatrix} -5 & -8 \\ 9/2 & 7  \end{pmatrix} \notin H$.

Comment: Could you perhaps recommend a small example where I can see that $hg'H\neq g'H$?  So that I might gain some intuition for this.

Comment: ok I see what you mean, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The kernel is what is called *the core* of $\,H\,$ = the largest normal subgroup of $\,G\,$ *contained* in the subgroup $\,H\,$ , and it equals

$$cor(H):=\bigcap_{g\in G}H^g=\bigcap_{g\in G}g^{-1}Hg$$