# When is kernel equal to the subgroup under action of left multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and let $H \leq G$ be any subgroup of $G$, supposing also $H$ has finite index $n$. Let $G$ act on the left cosets of $H$ by left multiplication; this induces the homomorphism $\varphi: G \to S_n$ given by $\varphi_x(gH)=xgH$.

The link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244497/the-kernel-of-a-group-action-defined-by-left-multiplication-on-left-cosets-of-h) asks a similar question and the posted answer mentions that under this action, $\mathrm{ker} \varphi$ is the **core** of $H$, i.e.

$$\mathrm{ker} \varphi = \mathrm{cor}(H) = \displaystyle\bigcap_{g \in G} gHg^{-1}$$

From this it follows that $\mathrm{ker} \varphi \leq H$.

What circumstances are necessary for $H = \mathrm{ker} \varphi$? One circumstances would be normality because then $\displaystyle\bigcap_{g \in G} gHg^{-1} = \displaystyle\bigcap_{g \in G} H = H$. Is this the only circumstance which would force $\mathrm{ker} \varphi = H$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you. I have fixed the inclusion so that it is correct now.

Comment: $H=\ker\varphi\iff\forall g\in G\quad H\subseteq gHg^{-1}\iff \forall g\in G\quad g^{-1}Hg\subseteq H\iff H$ is normal.